# perl: regex only matching some times

Tags: regex, perl

My regex is only matching the some of the expressions. When I test the expression on regex101.com it works just fine... what could be the issue with my code?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Example file, "surfacecoating":

```
[
('amino acids', 339, 350), 
('copper', 71, 77), 
('copper', 0, 6), 
('copper', 291, 297), 
('amino acids', 119, 130)]
```

What Dumper prints out for this file (note the first 3 matches are not returned):

```
'surfacecoating' => {
        'copper' => '291',
        'amino acids' => '119'
    },
```

the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

determine_cde_instances();

sub determine_cde_instances {
    my %cdeinstances;
    my %cde_instances;

    my $dir = "/results/CDE";
    opendir my $dh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $!";

    while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
        next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
        next if -d $file;

        open my $fh, '<', "$dir/$file" or die "Can't open $dir/$file: $!";

        while (my $line = <$fh>)
        {
                if (my ($instance) = $line =~ m/'(.*?)', (.*?), /)     
                {
                    my $instance = $1;
                    my $pos = $2;
                    $cde_instances{$file}{$instance} = $pos;
                }
        }
        close $fh;
    }    
    close $dh;

    print Dumper(\%cde_instances);
    return %cde_instances;
}
```

Comment: Your data file is a collection of sequences, but your code builds a (nested) associative array keyed on one member of the sequences.  An [array of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS) most obviously represents the structure in your data file — but what structure do you want in the code?  In other words, what would you have expected `Dumper` to output?

Comment: You are probably overwriting every `cde_instance` while adding them to to `$cde_instances` (it may take the first match as a key [just a guess], which is the same for `('copper', 0, 6)` and `('copper', 291, 297)`. Use another key (other than `$instance`) in:  `$cde_instances{$file}{$instance} = $pos;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing information in a hashref with keys `$instance`, but some of those keys in your data are the same on multiple lines.  So the key `'copper'` gets overwritten repeatedly, and you end up with only the last occurence.  The same happens with `'amino acids'`.

Since those keywords to-be-hash-keys repeat you can't go with a straight hash. You'll need to come up with a different data structure and which it will be depends on what you need to do with data.

A reasonable idea is to use an array, and perhaps an array with hashrefs, one for each pair

```
if ($line =~ m/'(.*?)', (.*?), /)     
{
    my %instance_pos = ($1, $2);

    push @{$cde_instances{$file}}, \%instance_pos;
}
```

Here each key `$file` in the hash `%cde_instances` has an arrayref as its value, carrying hashrefs for each instance-pos pair.  Of course, there are other choices, this is more of an example.

This can also be written as

```
if (my %instance_pos = $line =~ m/'(.*?)', (.*?), /) {
    push @{$cde_instances{$file}}, \%instance_pos;
}
```

or just

```
if ($line =~ m/'(.*?)', (.*?), /) {    
    push @{$cde_instances{$file}}, {$1, $2};
}
```

If you need to check/validate the captures then assign to two variables from regex.

---

With the above change and using `use Data::Dump qw(dd);` to print I get

```
{
  "data.txt" => [
    { "amino acids" => 339 },
    { copper => 71 },
    { copper => 0 },
    { copper => 291 },
    { "amino acids" => 119 },
  ],
}
```

Note that the numbers on the line after the first one aren't captured by your regex.  I take that to be done on purpose.  Please clarify it it isn't so.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much, your explanation made sense and I see where I went wrong; misunderstood a fundamental aspect of hashes.

Yes, I only need to save the first number, not the second number per line.

Thank you again!

Comment: @jelly Great, good to hear that :)  I added a couple of more ways to write that code (probably won't be new for you)

Comment: How would I directly access the key values of %instance_pos? (without going into a loop) like $cde_instances{$file}{$1}

Comment: @jelly  I am not sure what you mean.  You need to have a key and then retrieve its value.  This prints the hash `%h`, for example:  `foreach my $key (keys %h) { print "$key => $h{$key}\n" }`, or more simply `say "$_ => $h{$_}" for keys %h;`  (add `use feature qw(say);` on top so you can print using `say`, which adds a newline for us).  (I simply use `=>` as my choice when printing hashes, can put anything there)

Comment: @jelly Once you pull all keys with `keys` note that they come in random order, which may differ even across separate statements (and certainly across separte runs of the program).  It may be convenient to use `for (sort keys %h)`, as the keys then will always come out sorted the same way.  This is good for repeated reports, output, code reviews, debugging.

Comment: @jelly oh, I think I see what you meant, sorry.  So now `$cde_instances{$file}` is an arrayref, so you'd need to dereference: `$cde_instances{$file}->[0]` is its first element, which is a hashref. So to get the value you need to dereference again, now the hashref, `$cde_instances{$file}->[0]->{'amino acids'}` is the value.  Since you may not know which one is in which array slot you'd want to loop.

Comment: @jelly    Or, come up with a different data structure -- that's what I mean by "_depends on what you need to do with data_".  Or, once you fetched the data as above then populate another data structure, for easier specific handling.  Documentation: tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and cookbook on data structures [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).